# Magento: Get saved paypal credential in code

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have enabled paypal in Magnto 1.9
Now I want to call another paypal API in my Observer, for that I need paypal user,password and signature which I already saved while enabling paypal.

I want to fetch these details from admin to my code using config.

I have tried with below code but its not working.

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()); 
$Settings = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal_payments/payment/required_settings/express',$store);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You can use `Mage::getStoreConfig()` for get data from `core_config_data` table.

Comment: I have tried with ... $store = Mage::app()->getStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()); 
 $Settings = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal_payments/payment/required_settings/express',$store);

But its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()); 

$Email = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/general/business_paypal/general/business_accountaccount');
$UserName = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/wpp/api_username',$store);
$Password = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/wpp/api_password',$store);
$Signature = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/wpp/api_signature',$store);
```

With the above code we can fetch store wise PayPal credentials.

I have tested this..

Comment: The first attribute should be just `paypal/general/business_account`